# not able to connect through socket

Tags: java, sockets

I trying to connect two computers using socket connection.
I tried this code on same computer by entering its own IP address.
it works.
but it's not working in between two computer at my home.
similar code did worked on my college computers.
this is server side code

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;


    public class testserver {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ServerSocket listener = null;
            try {
                listener = new ServerSocket(7689);
                Socket other = listener.accept();
                System.out.println("connected");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is client side code

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class testclient {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter ip");
            String ip=sc.next();
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket(ip,7689);
                System.out.println("Connected");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

on server computer I typed ifconfig
got this line

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:1f:af:17:26:db  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5083 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5083 (5.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:85:56:49:dc:3d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.48  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be85:56ff:fe49:dc3d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13422 (13.4 KB)  TX bytes:15688 (15.6 KB)
```

and I am using this ip address from server inet addr:127.0.0.1 
next I started server code
nothing happens there

on client side I typed ifconfig too

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:54:c5:18:db 
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:25160 (25.1 KB)  TX bytes:25160 (25.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:56:f2:49:dc:0c 
          inet addr:192.168.2.13  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8256:f2ff:fe49:dc0c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3405 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2981248 (2.9 MB)  TX bytes:1352577 (1.3 MB)
```

then I started client side code on other computer
after a while this comes up

```
java testclient
Enter ip
192.168.0.48
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at testclient.main(testclient.java:13)
```

Comment: Do you have any firewalls?

Comment: Use `ipconfig` command in cmd window to find out the IPv4 address on Windows.

Comment: I am using address from ifconfig on linux(inet addr:192.168.0.48)

Comment: Define 'not working'. What exception do you get?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right I.P. address? You don't have any firewalls up? Try using the computer name instead of the i.p. and see if that helps a litte?

Comment: @EJP I am not getting any exception after ruuning, but both server. and clients time outs.

Comment: @3kings I tried after disabling firewall using sudo ufw disable.
I am using right address. How to use name instead of IP?

Comment: @Ruturaj That cannot possibly be correct. A timeout is manifested as an exception. What was it? You should have posted the entire stack trace in your question.

Comment: @EJP sorry sir I am running my code again I will edit my question when I get stacktrace

Comment: @EJP I have made changes. Please have a look. and my apologies for what I did before this. Having a bad day.

Comment: So you are entering an invalid address. So don't do that. Are both these computers on the same subnet? NB This is not a timeout, but it sure is an exception.

Comment: this are on different subnet. It comes after sometime, so I didn't read it and thought its a time-out. How to get address valid address? can you suggest?

Comment: If they're on different subnets it can't work. 192.168 is a private local subnet.

Comment: @EJP I have posted all info on network, I get on entering ifconfig.