# network setup for java code such that two computers on different networks/locations can use RMI

Tags: java, sockets, networking, rmi

I have to write a program for both sides, server and client (client and servers might have different location). Both sides communicate with each other using RMI. But I guess RMI doesn't work when computers on different sub-net, as RMI uses sockets. I want to know how I can setup a network such that two computers on different network appear to be on same subnet and RMI can work or any other way I can solve this problem. I had previous issues with sockets and I here's the link for the thread.

This is not a homework/school project, I am developing this software for my college.

[not able to connect through socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900547/not-able-to-connect-through-socket)

Answer (score 0):

> I guess RMI doesn't work when computers on different sub-net, as RMI uses sockets.

You guess wrong.

As long as the subnets have a route to each other and the appropriate ports are open they can communicate via sockets without problems.

In the case of RMI that usually means just port 1099, and taking the steps necessary to ensure that all remote objects are exported on that port. An in-memory Registry is also required, via LocateRegistry.createRegistry().

Your prior thread is of no relevance, as it only concerned an invalid IP address. If you think it constitutes proof of your bizarre claim about subnets and sockets, think again.

Comment: thank you for the rply. I have used sockets and RMI in my computer labs, they work fine on computers in my college lab, but when I tried to run same code anywhere else it didn't work. So I thought the problem would be same for RMI and sockets. I tried using LocateRegistry.createRegistry() for one code once, it still had some problems I couldn't solve. But I will try again and post results soon.